# Could not find a method onClick_Foo(View) - first time running on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, onclick, android-5.0-lollipop

I have an app that is about a year old, is on the Play store in beta, has gone through dozens of revisions.  All of a sudden I'm getting an error:

> Could not find a method onClick_Foo(View) in the activity class
>   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class 
>   android.widget.Button with id 'Foo_Button'

I'm getting this error on every one of the 7 buttons defined in my XML.  Since yesterday I've updating appcompat-v7 from 21.0.3 to 22.0.0 but also upgraded my testing device from KitKat to Lollipop for the first time.

I've double-checked spellings, capitalizations, none of the usual suspects explains this.  Here's a sample of the relevant code.  Let me know if you feel more would be helpful.  (The activity has 915 lines of code and the xml 186, so don't ask for the whole thing).  Testing on a Verizon Note 4 running Lollipop 5.0.1

activity_pick.xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:context="com.myapp.Pick"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/Ratings_Button"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:text="@string/Pick_Ratings_Button"
            android:onClick="onClick_Ratings"
            android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default"/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Pick.java:

```
public class Pick_Restaurant extends ActionBarActivity {
    public void onClick_Ratings (View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Ratings.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent,RATINGS);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 59
    versionName "0.6.4"
}

...

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile files('libs/mobileservices-1.1.5.jar')
}
```

Full Error on Log:

```
04-08 17:06:40.578    3508-3508/com.myapp.debug E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp.debug, PID: 3508
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onClick_Ratings(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'Ratings_Button'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4234)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5974)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onClick_Ratings [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:665)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4227)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5974)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1388)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1183)
```

Comment: That is strange.  Just a thought, you could try removing the `onClick` from the xml and call `setOnClickListener()` in your Activity.

Comment: I have an entire app's worth of onClicks set in my XMLs. I'm really not keen on recoding. This is something that has worked fine for months and is still a recommended way of handling buttons.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It looks like this is a new issue with Android 5.0.

From [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28345359/4409409), removing the `Theme` from the layout xml fixed this issue for them.

So in your case, remove the `theme` from your layout:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!--android:theme="@style/AppTheme"--> <!-- Remove this -->
    <!--................-->
  </ScrollView>
```

And add the theme in the AndroidManifest.xml instead:

```
android:theme="@android:style/AppTheme"
```

Comment: Oh man - I was so focused on the appcompat change I didn't realize that this was probably the first time I'd tested it on a Lollipop device. So this is a Lollipop issue and not an appcompat one. The theme fix works!

Comment: The same error happens when the theme is set Programmatically. Ex. setting custom theme for a DialogFragment.

Comment: Shame on Google! In my case this happens in standard preferences so I can't remove their theme. ;-/

Comment: thanks, weired bug, also have to remove style from all root and parent layouts, the best thing is that use a clicklistener ! I guess!

Answer (score 18):

I have just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653126/crash-when-clicking-button-with-custom-theme/31672941#31672941)

Basically, since Android 5.0 [individual views can be themed](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/training/material/theme.html).

To facilitate this, a `ContextThemeWrapper` is used to modify the underlying theme assigned to the `Activity` and assigned as the `Context` of the `View`. Since this `Context` is *not* your `Activity` anymore (the `Activity` has to be separate because it still has to return the original theme) the callbacks don't exist and you get the error you see.

If you don't really want to theme individual views the obvious solution is to not do so and theme the activity instead, as already suggested.

If you *do* indeed want to theme individual views, it appears that the `android:onClick` attribute cannot be used and you will have to fall back to manually assign an `OnClickListener`.

The question is, why did this work pre Lollipop? I can only speculate that because the functionality to theme individual views didn't exist, applying a `theme` attribute to a view would just change the default theme on the `Activity` as well.

Comment: You're right about why it work before Lollipop. And it won't work with support library either.

Answer (score 2):

Such things usually happens when you declare onClick in xml like you did:

```
android:onClick="onClick_Ratings"
```

Just make sure you are using this layout in that activity. Because the exception is clearly saying that your activity don't have the corresponding method which you did show you have:

```
public void onClick_Ratings (View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Ratings.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,RATINGS);
}
```

Also I guess you should declare the activity in your xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SendMessageActivity">
```

And actually log says:

> Could not find a method onClick_Ratings(View) in the activity class
>   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper

there is something wrong since `android.view.ContextThemeWrapper` is not an `Activity` and not the activity from your xml `com.myapp.Pick` (I assume Pick is an activity and not the fragment). Maybe try to clean up the project, ivalidate caches and restart.
If nothing helps I suggest you to return back to previuos version of support lib you'd mentioned OR to set onClickListener in code instead of xml.

Answer (score 2):

Removing android:theme works. But this is caused because using `android:onclick` in xml. If you use onClick in Java file, you can still use **android:theme**.

According to your code,

**activity_pick.xml** [Remove onclick here]

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Ratings_Button"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="@string/Pick_Ratings_Button"        
        android:background="@android:drawable/btn_default" />
```

Go to your Java File, that is, **pick.java** in your case:

```
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Ratings_Button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
        }
    });
```

Experienced the same error, app has stopped working, when material button was clicked programmatically helped me. Check it out :)