# Crash when clicking button with custom theme

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am creating a custom theme for button and using `android:onClick` event of Button from xml itself to handle the click of Button.

Due to some reason its crashing with below exception

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method MyOnClick(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'`

And its working fine if I just remove the theme attribute from the Button, below is my theme for Button

```
    <style name="ButtonTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">#FF000000</item>
    </style>
```

And my Button defined in xml as below,

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:onClick="MyOnClick"
        android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Here is my java code as well,

```
public void MyOnClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources()
                                   .getColor(R.color.statusBarColor));
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(getResources()
                                   .getColor(R.color.statusBarColor));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

So, what could be the reason for crashing? I am able to handle the click event if I remove `android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"` attribute from Button Widget from xml.

Comment: post your java code...

Comment: try using old way remove android:onClick  attribute and use Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
            }
        }); and don't forget to define button

Comment: @L-X but why? I want to add click event in xml itself, then what?

Comment: Buddy i guess the error is you are defining same onClick method to every button(Guessing you have more than 1 button) , but that is creating error try defining different function name to different button and define all those function in java ,Try it

Comment: @L-X I have only one button for now and if I have more than one then too I can define it by using `view.getId()` inside a switch case.

Comment: yes I was wrong can you try two things first check that this function is define in correct class where this layout has inflated and second try running your program by removing android:id attribute from button(as you have only 1 button now ) and remove switch from function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never seen anybody applying the `android:theme` attribute to an individual `View`, but after a bit of googling I found out that this is indeed possible, but only since Android 5.0.

A hint of this can be seen at the end [here](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/training/material/theme.html).

And some more detail [here](https://chris.banes.me/2014/11/12/theme-vs-style/).

As the second link explains, a `ContextThemeWrapper` is used to modify the theme associated with the base `Context`. However, since your `Activity` will need to hold on to its own theme, I can only imagine that a new `ContextThemeWrapper` is created and assigned as the new `Context` of your `View`. Since this new `Context` is not your `Activity` any more, your callback functions don't exist here and you get the error you describe.

You can use the debugger to prove this yourself (I used Android Studio, but you can probably use the IDE of your choice, the details might be different).

1. Run the app in debug mode with `theme` attribute set.
2. When you get the exception, the stacktrace will contain a reference to the `View` class where it invokes `onClick`.
3. Use this to add a breakpoint *before* the exception occurs.
4. Now run the app again in debug mode, click the button
5. When you hit the breakpoint evaluate the expression `getContext()`. You will see that this returns an object of type `ContextThemeWrapper` and it will have a member `mBase` which points back to your actual `Activity`, so `getContext()` itself does *not* return your `Activity` and does *not* have the callback functions you defined on your `Activity`.
6. Now remove the `theme` attribute, leave the breakpoint and run the app again.
7. When you hit the breakpoint, evaluate the expression `getContext()` again and you will see that this time it returns your `Activity` directly, which is why your callbacks work, if you don't set the `theme` attribute.

In short, it seems like you can't use the `android:onClick` attribute if you want to make use of this new feature, and you will have to manually assign an `OnClickListener` as described [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/Button.html)

Comment: We can use `android:onClick` with Fragments as well, I have used it!

Comment: I didn't say you can't use it, I said it's less useful. I believe so because you're creating fragments to modularise you're UI and then you're binding it strongly to a particular activity with onClick. Anyway, this was not the original question and is kinda besides the point.

Comment: I have removed the contentious statement at the end because it didn't add to the answer. I have also added debugging instructions that show exactly what's going on, so you can validate this for yourself.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that AppCompat v22.1 and above should allow individual widget theming from API 11 and above http://android-developers.blogspot.co.nz/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when we add style to `Button` It affects default android clickable behavior.

Try adding property `clickable="true"` in `<Button... />`

Or

You can also add `<item name="android:clickable" >true</item>` to style of button.

Comment: Button is already clickable, didn't you find that I get crash on clicking the button?

Comment: Its unexpected behavior. Use style instead of theme in button

Comment: @Azmi Ansari but I want to know the reason why theme is not working

Answer (score 0):

After spending so much time on this, the thing that worked for me was to apply the theme in code `setTheme(R.style.AppToolbar);` in the onCreate() instead of ripping out all the android:OnClick from all the layouts.