# Java, XML - onClick crashes my program

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick

UPDATE: So I forgot to clarify this, but the button is at first non-existent on the App UNTIL dynamically added. Once the layout has been inflated with the button, the button then causes the crash. I apologize for the issues that came up from this development.

So there is a button that keeps crashing my program no matter what (unless I remove the onClick). I tested every line in my Java code to see what was causing it but even after leaving it empty, it still crashes it.

From my MainActivity.Java, the method that causes the crash:

```
public void changeState(View v) {
    String owe = "O";
    String debt = "D";

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.decl);

    if (button.getText().toString().equals("D")) {
        button.setText("O");
    } else {
        button.setText(("D"));
    }
}
```

Also from the Java file, the layout inflation method that creates the button causing the crashes:

```
public void create(MenuItem v) {
    newContact = new LinearLayout(this);
    newContact.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.newcontact, null);

    view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
        public void onSwipeRight() {
        }
    });

    // insert into main view
    ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.insert);
    insertPoint.addView(view);
}
```

The above Java code inflates this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#CCFFFF"
android:weightSum="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:shadowColor="#0066FF"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#8F8F8F" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/decl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="D"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>


    <!--android:onClick="changeState"-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">\

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/amount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="(Ex 123.25)"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:shadowColor="#0066FF"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#8F8F8F"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/owed"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="(Ex $, coffee)"
            android:shadowColor="#0066FF"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorHint="#8F8F8F"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#CFCFCF"
    />
```

The Button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/decl"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".75"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="D"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:onClick="changeState"
/>
```

Crash log

```
08-09 22:44:22.792    1951-1951/com.xephos.detra E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xephos.detra, PID: 1951
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method changeState(View) in the activity class android.app.Application for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'decl'
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at ...
```

Comment: And the crash log says...?

Comment: add the crash log please

Comment: Edited @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz

Comment: Wait, you put `public void changeState(View v) {` and so on in your XML file? That's Java code.

Comment: Ah sorry for the mistake. It's java. @immibis

Comment: If you are using Android 5.0 and if you are using the `theme` tag in the xml, try to remove it... Apparently [could be an issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29525901/3998458)

Comment: @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz Android 5.1 I believe? How can I check? Also attempted to look for "theme" tag but couldn't find it in the activity_main.xml and the other two xmls I'm using.

Comment: I guess API 22 are for Android 5.1, you can check in your project properties

Comment: http://puu.sh/jvWDm/33d5bbc618.PNG This would be it, correct @AlexandroSifuentesDíaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
Put this in your MainActivity after setContentView():

```
 public void create(MenuItem v) {
        newContact = new LinearLayout(this);
        newContact.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.newcontact, null);
        Button b = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.decl);
        if (b != null) {
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Button b = (Button)v;
                    if ("D".equals(b.getText().toString())) {
                        b.setText("O");
                    } else {
                        b.setText(("D"));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        view.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
            }
        });

        // insert into main view
        ViewGroup insertPoint = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.insert);
        insertPoint.addView(view);
    }
```

Comment: If someone downvote without comment why it's annoying.

Comment: Ah, I thought it was a String issue so I made those, but them commented them out for now. And I tried your code, still the same issue. D:

Comment: getting an error saying that b is accessed from within the inner class and needs to be declared final, which is something I don't want. :(

Comment: just declare it final or reflect it

Comment: Issue still persists after trying final. How do you reflect?

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. This is very odd. I made another app recently using buttons too but it had no issues whatsoever. :/

Comment: What you mean by issues?

Comment: Like the current issue. I edited my post and now contains the error in the current app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86578/discussion-between-yshahak-and-xephos).